# Only allow English characters/letters/numbers and a few special characters

Tags: php, string, filter

My problem is that I am making a small search engine from scratch, but it gets messed up if I search in Russian/any other language besides English. I was hoping some one could give me a code with regex that could filter out (not just detect, automaticallt filter out) Russian letters, or any other letters except the English letters, and keyboard special characters (-/:;()$&@". - etc).
Later on, I will implement different language support for my engine, but for now, I want to finish the base of the engine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But regex is designed for cases exactly like yours, why would you not want to use it?

Comment: If there is no alternatives to regex, I guess it'll be fine. I just can't learn regex, it seems too complex for me.

Comment: @TillHelge the answer there is a regex solution.

Comment: No need to *learn* regular expressions for this - simple copy & pasting will suffice.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV True...because it's the reasonable solution and there is no real reason to avoid regular expressions. ;) Your solution sure is elegant though.

Comment: @TillHelge Hmmm yeah you make a point, thanks :)

Comment: `filter_var($yourString, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, $options)`. See http://php.net/filter_var

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may create an array of allowed characters and then filter those that are not allowed:

```
$allowed = array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'), range(0, 9), array(' ', '+', '/', '-', '*', '.')); // Create an array of allowed characters

$string = 'This is allowed and this not é Ó ½ and nothing 123.'; // test string

$array = str_split($string); // split the string (character length = 1)

echo implode('', array_intersect($array, $allowed)); // Filter and implode !
```

[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/C91uzD).

Comment: This seems very interesting. Thanks a lot, I'll try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate? A regex will read the contents of the string, so better do it yourself. Read the characters of the string and check their corresponding ASCII value.

Create a hashset like structure with [SplStorageObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) and check manually if the characters fall in the desired set. You can add any characters that you want to read to this set.

EDIT - You might want to use regex too - something like [a-zA-Z0-9,./+&-] but using a set could allow you to expand your search engine gradually by adding more characters to the known-characters set.

Answer (score -1):

this may not be the most effective way but it works :)

```
$str='"it is a  simple test \ + - é Ó ½ 213  /:;()$&@".~" ';
$result= preg_replace('/[^\s\w\+\-\\":;@\(\)\$\&\.\/]*/', '', $str);
echo $result;
```

but you need to add every special characters.